# How can I use Unicode/Korean characters in a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby

I've been Googling this for the last two hours, and there are tons and tons of StackOverflow posts claiming to solve the problem, and not a single one of them has worked for me. I'm confused and terribly frustrated.

I have a text file that contains Korean text. I simply want to read it into my Ruby 2.1 program and do some stuff with it.

But whenever I read the file in, all the Unicode characters get replaced by `\u2713` and the like.

I've Googled this issue, and the suggestions are to:

- Put `# encoding: UTF-8` as the first line of the program. This changed nothing.
- Call `encode('utf-8')` on the strings. This changed nothing.
- Call `force_encoding('utf-8')` on the strings. This changed nothing.
- Change `$KCODE` to 'UTF-8'. This changed nothing.

What's especially frustrating is that I wrote the original text file using a Ruby program in the first place. I pulled text off a webpage and wrote it to a file, and the Korean characters were written just fine. I just can't read them back *out of* that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the encoding when you read the file using the `encoding` option to `File.read`:

```
correctly_encoded_text = File.read("my_korean_text.txt", encoding: "UTF-8")
```